# How to resolve Ubuntu 22.04 Gtk-messages seen when Firefox installed as snap used in terminal

Tags: 22.04

To reproduce Gtk-Messages, using Ubuntu 22.04 (recently upgraded from 21.10 with all upgrades applied):

input at terminal prompt: `firefox`
output seen

```
Gtk-Message: 19:38:32.602: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
Gtk-Message: 19:38:33.504: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 19:38:33.553: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

this does not seem to inhibit firefox in any visible way but is also seen in Qt6 Creator 7.0 WebAssembly application output. `firefox` in Ubuntu 22.04 is installed from `snap` by default.

I have seen similar questions asked and attempted to resolve in the manner suggested in answers (not all were relevant) and problem not resolved.  I have also tried removing and purging `firefox` and then installing problem still appears.  It may be related to type of `snap` confinement used but I am unsure of this.

Comment: Since I have been seeing these Gtk-Messages often.  How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package using latest stable release: Source: OMG Ubuntu did eliminate them.  It may introduce other issues.